# What could scrollTop() keep off from working?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to scroll to point on screen. That's my Code

```
$('#MainNavigation .link a').click(function() {
    alert('start');
    var linkClicked = $(this).attr('data-opsection');
    var destination = parseInt( $('section[data-opsection="' + linkClicked +'"]').position().top );
    $("html").animate({scrollTop: destination}, 500 );
    alert('done');
});
```

both alerts are displayed, all variable values are correct, the consol logs no errors but the page doesn't scroll.

here's my markup, perhapse someone knows a solution

```
<div id="ContentContainer">
    ...
    ...
    <section id="SID-20" data-opsection="commerce" class="onepage-section cf">
        ...
    </section> 

    <section id="SID-22" data-opsection="workout" class="onepage-section cf">
        ...
    </section> 

    <section id="SID-21" data-opsection="ueber-das-projekt" class="onepage-section wrapper cf">
        ...
    </section> 

    <section id="SID-23" data-opsection="kontakt" class="onepage-section cf">
        ...
    </section> 
    ...
    ...
</div>
```

Here's a part of the CSS, I'm using [Pushy](http://christopheryee.ca/pushy/) so overflow-x: hidden is required. But even without, it doesn't work.

```
html,
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); /* disable webkit tap highlight */
    height: 100%; /* fixes focus scrolling in Safari (OS X) */
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #879299; /*#465762;*/
    background: #465762;
}

#ContentContainer {
    position: relative;
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

And here comes the menu markup

```
<nav id="MainNavigation" class="pushy pushy-open">
    <ul>
        ...
        <li class="link ">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-opsection="ueber-das-projekt">Über das Projekt</a>
        </li>

        <li class="link last">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-opsection="kontakt">Kontakt</a>
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Try `console.log(destination)` to confirm it's an integer.

Comment: It wasn't an integer, I updated my code, but still the same behavior

Comment: Can you post the mark up for the "#MainNavigation .link a" structure?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/qdk39anv/ , http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/qdk39anv/1/ . This works as expected...

Comment: I just tried to call the function on an random element with a fixed scroll position from 500. But It still doesn't work. The the problem be somewhere in the css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS is fine, it looks like how I would do it and should work OK!

Here is a fiddle showing it working correctly:

http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/8euussh7/

I think, looking at your markup, that what is happening is that the body and html are set to height: 100% but if #ContentContainer is higher than the viewport height, then your html height is equal to whatever is the height of #ContentContainer, so in other words there's nothing to actually scroll!

In otherwords, unfortunately, I don;t think you can have the body set to overflow: hidden and refuse to fix the height of #ContentContainer - nothing will scroll!

**Solution 1 - fix ContentContainer**

If you set the height of #ContentContainer to be that of the viewport:

```
$("#ContentContainer").css({height: ($(window).height()-80) + "px"});
```

and add overflow: scroll to your CSS for #ContentContainer:

```
#ContentContainer {
    position: relative;
    background: #ffffff;
    overflow: scroll
}
```

does that work for you? Demo of this here:

http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/8euussh7/3/

Update: better demo, with your nav markup: http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/8euussh7/4/

**Solution 2 - allow the body to scroll**

Remove overflow: hidden from the body and you can scroll the body, as shown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/8euussh7/5/

**Solution 3 - an extra wrapper**

If you can get an extra wrapper div into your markup just inside the body then we can use that to handle the scrolling. The body can keep the overflow-x:hidden and the #ContentContainer does not need to be sized.

http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/8euussh7/7/

Comment: I updated my Answer. ContentContainer can't have a fixed height. I also doesn't want to scroll in this container (my fault, my posted code was wrong) I want to use 'html'

Comment: It destroys my whole layout but now it works :D is there a way to scroll in body or html without destroying my design?

Comment: just added that, but alas it requires you to remove overflow:hidden from the body - no easy answer yet...

Comment: that's not nice but it works :/ is there no other way?

Comment: howabout an extra div as a wrapper around everything to handle the scrolling? I'll post a link...

Comment: would be great! Perhaps this is a possible solution

Comment: This also doesn't solve it like it should. but thank you very much!

Comment: ah well, thanks for the upvote and the tick meanwhile, I hope you get something working well for you eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works for me

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#[NAME YOUR ELEMENT]").offset().top }, 500);
```

We have that running in an mvc 4 site